# How can I display the mouse coordinates in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Hi I'm trying to display or capture the mouse coordinates in my program.
In this program, you can click on any button and corresponding image will appear.
I want to display the mouse coordinates on this too.

I tried the following code but it doesn't work.
Please let me know where I am going wrong.

```
   canvas.on('mouse:down', function(options){
   getMouse(options);// its not an event its options of your canvas object
});


function getMouse(options) {
    console.log(options);// you can check all options here
    console.log(options.e.clientX);
}
```

The fiddle is:
http://jsfiddle.net/wv9MU/9/

Comment: @Sneaky no no error as such. but I cant see the displayed x and y mouse coordinates . Can you help ?

Comment: @Sneaky Can you please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

This could be your getMouse function:

```
function getMouse(options) {
    p = canvas.getPointer(options.e);
    document.getElementById('mouse').value = '' + p.x.toFixed() + ', ' + p.y.toFixed(0);
}
```

This is a unpdated working fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/wv9MU/22/