# How to get x and y coordinates in Javascript on a canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Hi I am trying to get the upper Left and lower right coordinates of the rectangle on the canvas.
you can draw the canvas by clicking Rectangle checkbox and using the mouse down event. How can I display x and y coordinates.
Please help
http://jsfiddle.net/K5wcs/2/

```
 <input type="text" id="XCoordinate" value="" >
    <span>Metric</span>
  <input type="text" id="YCoordinate" value="" >
    <span>Metric</span>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting mouse location in canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114465/getting-mouse-location-in-canvas)

Comment: Can you please add in the code as I am still getting a issue. its not displaying

Comment: Also dupe from same user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669974/how-can-i-display-the-mouse-coordinates-in-fabric-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer:

```
        mySel.x = mx - offsetx;
        mySel.y = my - offsety;


$mouse.innerHTML = "(" + mySel.x + "," + mySel.y + ")" ;
```

and in the end add this to HTML

```
 <div id="MouseCoords"></div>
```